# Base of topology

Tags: general-topology

X = $\mathbb R^2$,
$\tau$ = {$\emptyset, \mathbb R^2$, { (x, y) $\in \mathbb R^2$ | $x^2+y^2<r $}, r $\in \mathbb R$, $r>0$}. 
I need to find the base with the smallest candinality of (X, $\tau$) topological space. How can I do it? What should I start with? Thank You for all help in advance.

Comment: it is a topology: empy set and whole set are contained, unions are trivially contained and so are finite intersections.

Comment: You are right !

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

1. Prove that there exists no finite basis (take $r^\ast:=\frac 12\min\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$, where $r_i$ are the radii of the sets you considered as potential basis).
2. The existence of a countable basis is easy, by just considering rational radii.